# Indirect reference to bash array creates an empty element. Why?

Tags: arrays, bash

Why does an empty bash array have length 1? This is driving me nuts. Can anyone explain what happened with `array3`?

```
$ bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.11(1)-release
$ set | egrep '(array1|array2|array3|indirect)'
$ array1=(); echo ${#array1[@]}
0
$ declare -a array2; echo ${#array2[@]}
0
$ indirect=array1; array3=${!indirect}; echo ${#array3[@]}
1
$ echo "what's in here? ->${array3[0]}<-"
what's in here? -><-
$ set | egrep '(array1|array2|array3|indirect)'
array1=()
array3=
indirect=array1
```

I got into this by trying to a "unique appender" function for bash arrays, the result kept having extra empty elements at the beginning. Thanks for listening ;-)

Comment: Consider using `declare -p` to inspect variables, rather than `set`; it's rather significantly more explicit.

Comment: BTW, if you have bash 4.3, why aren't you using namevars for this? It's literally exactly what they're made for.

Comment: ...the other way to have unique appends, by the way, is to use an associative array and add keys. That's O(1) not O(n), so if you don't need ordering guarantees on traversal it's significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

#### What's happening

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
array1=( )
indirect=array1
array3=${!indirect}
```

...this is not, *and never was*, syntax to create a copy of an indirectly-named array's contents. Instead, it's assigning an empty string (the first entry in the empty `array1`) to `array3`:

```
$ declare -p array3
declare -- array3=""
```

To consider a less-confusing example:

```
$ array1=( hello cruel world )
$ indirect=array1
$ echo ${!indirect}
hello
```

...which is to say that you're indirectly performing the assignment `array3=$array1` (assigning the first element in `array1` to a string named `array3`), **not** `array3=( "${array1[@]}" )` (creating an array named `array3` with the same contents as the array `array1`).

---

#### Indirect array mutation with namevars (ie. indirect appends, the right way)

If you're targeting bash 4.3, there's a new addition to the language (or, rather, a recently adopted ksh feature) intended for exactly this purpose: namevars.

```
append_if_unique() {
  local varname=$1; shift

  # create a new global array if our destination doesn't already exist
  declare -p "$varname" >/dev/null 2>&1 || declare -g -a "$varname"

  # avoid nasty corner cases around locals colliding with destination
  if [[ $varname =~ ^(varname|var|value|new_value)$ ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: cannot append to a variable named $varname" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  local -n var="$varname"
  local value new_value

  for new_value; do
    for value in "${var[@]}"; do
      if [[ $value = "$new_value" ]]; then
        continue 2 # skip to next proposed new value
      fi
    done
    var+=( "$new_value" )
  done
}
```

...thereafter:

```
append_if_unique myarray "first value" "second value" "first value"
append_if_unique myarray "first value" "third value"
declare -p myarray
```

...will emit...

```
declare -a myarray='([0]="first value" [1]="second value" [2]="third value")'
```

---

#### Unique appending in bash, the easy way

...however, barring a requirement for order preservation, you don't need a fancy function at all. Just use an associative array:

```
declare -A myarray
myarray["first value"]=1
myarray["second value"]=1
myarray["third value"]=1
myarray["third value"]=1
```

...thereafter:

```
# iterate over keys with ${!yourarray[@]} to access
for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$key"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your many helpful comments. I had already discovered my erroneous assumption that an indirect reference would work. I _knew_ that `${myarray}` yields the first element, if anything was going to work it would be `clone=${!indirect[@]}`. Which it doesn't. The idea of using the keys to store my values and letting the array structure guarantee uniqueness is sick, thanks for that!

Comment: Glad to help! Is there anything else I can/should cover for you to consider the question fully answered?